# Confused about CSS Display: table and the way contents of cells line up

Tags: css

I have a web application and I am using the CSS display: table.  I have a wrapper and this contains two columns called sbr and bdy.  I've no problem getting this to look like a table BUT it seems like the contents of one table cell effect the other. I made a fiddle for this. Notice that the CCC doesn't appear at the top in the right hand cell. The position of the CCC depends on code in the left cell.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cdtua/)

Can anyone explain why this is. I would have thought each cell would be isolated from the others.

```
<div id="wrp">
   <div id="row">
      <div id="sbr">
         <div class="sbr_bdy">
            <h4>AAAA</h4>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div id="bdy">CCC</div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrp {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: table;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    top: 110px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.sbr_bdy {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: red;
}

#row { display: table-row; }
#sbr,
#bdy { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#bdy {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will move CCC to the very top of the cell. Now you can use padding to get a little spacing :)
The current behaviour is btw how a table would behave

Comment: Thanks Tim (and others). I just spent 1 1/2 hours on this and you answered my question in just 2 minutes. You're all a great help.

Comment: No problem, that's our job :)